# Angular clearing input problems with only whitespace (Current stable v1.5)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, string, whitespace, trim

JSfiddle code at the bottom

**My problem:** If an `<input>` field has whitespace in it and you "clear" the value with angular by setting its scope value to an empty string, it leaves the whitespace in the input field.

**The reason:** I understand why it is doing it, as the angular digest doesn't see a change, since it already has the scope variable empty due to trimmed whitespace via ng-trim.

**My question:** Is there a *proper* way to make sure the input field gets blanked out? I know of multiple solutions, but all of them are hacks or wouldn't work.

- Set the scope value to null, and then to blank after a $timeout. But this could cause problems due to the code expecting only strings in the scope value.
- Set the element to ng-trim, but I *like* having the value automatically trimmed
- Empty the input field with jquery (or directly setting the element's value). This is probably the solution I am going to end up going with (a function that clears the input and blanks the scope variable at the same time), but I'm hoping there is something not quite so hacky.

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/0kf84g5o/3/

### **HTML**

```
<div ng-app=MyApp>
  <div ng-controller="TestCtl">
    Press "tabs and spaces", add spaces and/or tabs, and then press "blank out'<br>
    <input ng-model=TestInput id=TestInput>
    <input type=button value="abc" ng-click="ChangeTestValue('abc')">
    <input type=button value="Tabs and spaces"ng-click="ChangeTestValue('\t  \t')">
    <input type=button value="Blank out" ng-click="ChangeTestValue('')">
    <input type=button value="Null out" ng-click="ChangeTestValue(null);">
    <pre>
      Angular Value: --{{TestInput}}--

      JSONified Angular Value: --{{TestInputJSON}}--

      Actual input value JSONified: --{{TestInputActualJSON}}--
    </pre>
  </div>
</div>
```

### **Javascript**

```
var MyApp=angular.module('MyApp', []);
MyApp.controller('TestCtl', function($scope, $timeout) {
    //Update the value programatically
    $scope.TestInput='Start text';
    $scope.ChangeTestValue=function(Str) {
        $scope.TestInput=Str;
    };

    //Update TestInputJSON
    $scope.$watch('TestInput', function(NewVal) { //When angular values changes
        scope.TestInputJSON=JSON.stringify(NewVal);
    });

    //Update TestInputActualJSON
    $scope.$watch('TestInput', function(NewVal) {  //When angular value changes
        $timeout(UpdateTestInputActualJSON, 1); //Wait for 1ms to update so the new value is alread set
    });
    $('#TestInput').on('keyup paste', UpdateTestInputActualJSON); //On a jquery event
    function UpdateTestInputActualJSON(e) //Do the actual update of TestInputActualJSON
    {
        $scope.TestInputActualJSON=JSON.stringify($('#TestInput').val());
        if(e) //Call angular digest if coming from jQuery
            $scope.$apply();
    }
});
```

Comment: Why is this a problem? Usually, if you use angular, you're not concerned with the input values, only with the model values.

Comment: It bugs me. When I clear a form for a user, I expect it to clear the form. It's sloppy not to.

Comment: Agreed. Have you tried just using button type=reset ?

Comment: Indeed, I had thought about it and it is a possible solution. I already have to create a hidden submit button that is "clicked" when I want to submit the form so that it does its HML5 validation. I guess this would be no different. It doesn't solve the actual problem, but it is a good idea.